# Accessing Data Outside of Closure

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I have an array  in my class that I'm trying to fill within a closure. However, when I try to access/print the array contents, it seems to be empty outside of the closure. How do I store the data for use outside of the closure?

```
for index in 0..<6 {
        let picNumber = index + 1
        if let pica = currentuser.objectForKey("pic\(picNumber)") as? PFFile {
            pica.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data:NSData!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    self.pic1 = UIImage(data: data)
                    var imageS = scaleImage(self.pic1!, and: 200)
                    self.imagesForSection0.append(imageS)
                }
            })
            println(self.imagesForSection0)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not empty outside the Closure

The method `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` is **async**,it means that it will return first.So,you see nothing in print function.

Document

> Asynchronously gets the data from cache if available or fetches its contents from the network.

Edit

```
for index in 0..<6 {
    let picNumber = index + 1
    if let pica = currentuser.objectForKey("pic\(picNumber)") as? PFFile {
        pica.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data:NSData!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                self.pic1 = UIImage(data: data)
                var imageS = scaleImage(self.pic1!, and: 200)
                self.imagesForSection0.append(imageS)
            }
        println(self.imagesForSection0)
        //Then call reload data
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Still a bit confused, the self.imagesForSection0 array acts like it's empty in other parts of the file. It's supposed to show the retrieved images in a collection view but it's showing blank. Should I use a different method?

Comment: You should put the `println` function inside the closure,and after the array is changed call `reloaddata `

Comment: Ah perfect. Thanks so much!